# AJAX Based Dynamic Image Serving - Google App Engine Python 2.7

Tags: ajax, image, google-app-engine, python-2.7

The instructions from Google about dynamically serving images with GAE are here: https://developers.google.com/appengine/articles/python/serving_dynamic_images
The only problem is that this method does not use AJAX, and I don't think it is as efficient as I would expect.

I am trying to use AJAX with GAE Python 2.7 to serve multiple images dynamically, but I am focusing on serving one right now.

Python Server Side Code:

```
class GetImage(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        problem = Problem.all()[0]
        if(problem and problem.prompt_image):
            self.response.headers['Content-Type'] = "image/png"
            self.response.out.write(problem.prompt_image)
```

Client Side AJAX Code:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "/img",
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "html",
    success: function(msg){
        $("#right").append("<img>"+msg+"</img>");
    }
});
```

The problem that I am facing is that I don't know how to serve the blobstore contents via AJAX to the DOM. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Thanks!

Edit: voscausa's solution seems to be on the right track. However, it requires a blob_key. My model is as follows:

```
class Problem(db.Model):
    prompt_image = db.BlobProperty()
```

I can't seem to figure out how to get the Blob Key from the db.BlobProperty. Is this possible?

Comment: did you need to view it in a browser or you need to download it.

Comment: @Peter In the complete system, the user would press a button, and this would trigger an AJAX event. Since at that time, the page would already be loaded, I felt that POST was appropriate.

Comment: @Ankur The image would be displayed in the browser. Essentially, I have a form that has a defined structure. As the user navigates through their choices, new images load and are placed in the slots.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem gave me a real headache. Thanks to everyone, especially voscausa who put me on the right path to getting the solution. There is a lot of old material out there, this is the solution I used:
https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/blobstore/overview#Uploading_a_Blob
(see complete sample application)

```
import os
import urllib
import webapp2

from google.appengine.ext import blobstore
from google.appengine.ext.webapp import blobstore_handlers

class MainHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
  def get(self):
    upload_url = blobstore.create_upload_url('/upload')
    self.response.out.write('<html><body>')
    self.response.out.write('<form action="%s" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">' % upload_url)
    self.response.out.write("""Upload File: <input type="file" name="file"><br> <input type="submit"
        name="submit" value="Submit"> </form></body></html>""")

class UploadHandler(blobstore_handlers.BlobstoreUploadHandler):
  def post(self):
    upload_files = self.get_uploads('file')  # 'file' is file upload field in the form
    blob_info = upload_files[0]
    self.redirect('/serve/%s' % blob_info.key())

class ServeHandler(blobstore_handlers.BlobstoreDownloadHandler):
  def get(self, resource):
    resource = str(urllib.unquote(resource))
    blob_info = blobstore.BlobInfo.get(resource)
    self.send_blob(blob_info)

app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([('/', MainHandler),
                               ('/upload', UploadHandler),
                               ('/serve/([^/]+)?', ServeHandler)],
                              debug=True)
```

Answer (score 1):

To serve an image from the blobstore with a GET:

```
http://{{ your_appid }}.appspot.com/imgserve/{{ blob_key }}
```

Code to serve image from the blobstore:

```
class ImgServe(blobstore_handlers.BlobstoreDownloadHandler):

    def get(self, blob_key):                                       

    blob_info = blobstore.BlobInfo.get(blob_key)     
    self.send_blob(blob_info, save_as=True)


app = webapp2.WSGIApplication(
                          [
                           ('/imgserve/([^/]+)?', ImgServe),
                          ], debug=True)
```

Comment: voscausa, thanks for the rapid reply. I am a little confused about your answer. Based on my understanding, when the user wants to get an image, I can have my JQuery JS make an AJAX call, and then take the returned data and display it on the page. It seems that your solution requires the user to navigate to a URL.

Comment: To explain it in your words: an AJAX GET is like navigating to an url. An image url in a webpage is an image GET = go to url, which shows the image. And <img src="url" alt="some_text"> : show image in webpage.

Comment: To explain it in your words: an AJAX GET is like navigating to an url, which returns the image. An image url in a webpage is an image GET = go to url, which shows / returns the image. And <img src="url" alt="some_text"> : show image in webpage

Comment: Good point. I understand this better now. One problem that I have in implementing your suggestion is that my model is using db.BlobProperty() storage. Is it possible to get a key to the blob through this?

Comment: If you use a datastore blob_property your original code must work. But I suggest to change the post into a get. Get is easy to test :  type the url of the image in your browser. http://appid.appspot.com/img/test_image.png